# Does Mindy St Claire's "Medium Place" have a Janet?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-good-place

In Season 1, Episode 12 of The Good Place we find out about the existence of the Medium Place, created especially for Mindy St Claire. Later, in Season 2, Episode 4 we are told that every neighbourhood in both the Good Place and the Bad Place needs a Janet to run and maintain it over the long term.

Given that when we arrive in the Medium Place, Mindy says she hasn't spoken to anyone in 30 years before Eleanor, Jason and Janet show up, is there any evidence that the Medium Place has a Janet?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no Janet in the Middle place.

This is why she wants someone to bring her some cocaine, from a neighborhood that has a functioning Janet.

Comment: Good observation

Comment: There is a Neutral Janet, but she services the Neutral Zone, not the Middle Place. The Neutral Zone is where the bureaucrats who administer the rules laid out by the demons and angels work.

Answer (score 0):

> We are told that every neighbourhood in both the Good Place and the Bad Place needs a Janet to run and maintain it over the long term.

The Medium Place is no neighbourhood, because neighbourhoods are, by definition, composed of neighbours, but there are no neighbours there.

Having no neighbours, there is no civic life to be maintained by a Janet. A Janet has no use there. And which kind of Janet could be deployed there? A "Medium Janet"? How would be one of such?

Also, the Medium Place was not a part of "the plan", it was a makeshift place for solving an exceptional case, that is, for throwing Mindy St. Claire's and forgetting her there. Who would waste time creating a new type of Janet just for one woman (that, by the way, would really prefer a "James")?

Answer (score -1):

No, there isnt a Janet in the medium place, but how ever i guess that the most near janet bring her the things that she wanted like food, but in some way the bad place made minor changes so that it would be medium

It may be like this

1. Mindy thinks in something
2. Janet recives the message
3. The message is passed to a bad place janet
4. She makes some changes
5. The thing that she asked was bring to her

I think it is like this because in the series there is a scene were they are dipers and sex toys, how ever they were medium since they were a little bit changed so it was bad but not so bad, also i think that she is the only one that gets what she thinks rather than say the name janet because it is only 1 person, and if this was done in a neighborhood it would be a chaos and janet couldnt resist the amount of things that the people asked, like a pc, in some episode eleanore asked for a popcorn river and she says that it was a little dificult to mantain because she neded to "render all the popcorn"

Comment: Do you have some reference for this claim (that a good and a bad Janet collaborate to get Mindy stuff)?